# Algolia Nodejs Firebase syncing - .on('child_added') won't get called

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I have a NodeJS script in which I'm watching trees in my Firebase database to see if an entry has been added/changed/removed via the `child_added`, `childed_changed`, and `child_removed` properties of the Firebase Admin `.on()` function in order to sync entries with my Algolia database.

The problem is that when I add/change/remove an item on these trees, the functions themselves never get fired.

However, when I start the script, I also have a `.once('value', initialImport)` function I call that works fine.

So for example, here is my relevant `child_added` code in my NodeJS script:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});
var database = firebaseAdmin.database();

var algolia = algoliasearch(process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID, process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY);
var users = algolia.initIndex('users');

var bandsRef = database.ref("/social/bands");

bandsRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateBandIndexRecord);

/**
 *  Add or update a band index record
 */
function addOrUpdateBandIndexRecord(dataSnapshot) {

  // Get Firebase object
  var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();

  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;

  // Add or update object
  bands.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase<>Algolia band object saved', firebaseObject.objectID);
  });
}
```

This never runs :/ Is there something I'm doing wrong? This used to work once upon a time.

UPDATE: The issue I was having was that I was also calling a `.once()` on the ref that I was adding the `.on('child_added')` and this was causing a conflict. Once I removed the code for `.once()`, it solved the syncing issue. In order to do an initial import, you'll most likely want that code in a separate node file. This is what worked for me, anyway.

Comment: Hi Stevie, is this the full code of your failing service? Because you register `addOrUpdateUserIndexRecord` while the function is named `addOrUpdateBandIndexRecord` and then your create an index named users but you never use it. Let me know

Comment: Hey there @vvo, My apologies. I have updated my code all to be the correct snippets. There's a bit more code in my file, but it's more or less the same. This example has all the relevant code. Do you have any what's going on here?

Comment: Can you console.log jsut before bands.saveIndex the firebaseObject? so we can check what's hapening